# UIView Under Nav and Tab Bars

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, storyboard, constraints

Using storyboard and Swift, I have a view controller which has two elements on it. A UITextField, and a UIView, which I use merely to give a colored border to the UITextField.  The UITextField is a child of the UIView.  See:

[image]

The problem I am having is that despite having set the top bar and bottom bar simulated metrics attributes to Opaque Navigation Bar and Opaque Tab Bar respectively, See:

[image]

When the app builds and runs the top of the UIView is always underneath the nav bar.  My over all feeling is that this is somehow a constraints issue but I have not been able to find the solution to it.  How do I set the constraints so that the UIView is always immediately underneath the nav bar, and the bottom of the view is always just on top of the tab bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your UIView in storyboard and assign constraints to the top margins and to bottom margins.  There is a 'Pin' button you use to do this that looks something like a Tie-Fighter ship in Star Wars, it is located at the bottom right of your storyboard view.

This will set margins to stretch to top and bottom always.

Comment: I see the Tie Fighter button, but I cannot select anything in it.  Everything is grayed out and nothing within it responds to mouse clicks except for the 'Update' drop down.

Comment: @zeeple You have to create a new `UIView` within that view, than do this with that view.

Comment: I removed the UIView and just used the view that comes along with the view controller.  And incidentally, the reason everything was all grayed out in the Tie Fighter control was because I'd had the view selected that was a part of the view controller, and you cannot add constraints to that.  After an infinity of tweaking and adjusting, this now works as expected.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That is what the layout guides are for. Pin the top to the Top Layout Guide and the bottom to the Bottom Layout Guide. The guides will always move to adjust for any top and bottom bars.